# how to I rotate interface in an active script?

Tags: php, curl, interface, rotation, ip

I have a situation where a server I am making a number of big calls to will just lock and the only way to get the data is by restarting the script completely.

As a work around I would like the script to switch interfaces (forcing a new connection) every 3 or 4 cycles in my loop. I have 3 interfaces with different IP addresses to chose from.

code:

```
function callapi($url, $flags, $apikey, $apisecret){
        $nonce=time();
        $uri = 'http://mytestapi.api/schmuckatelli&nonce='.$nonce;
        $sign=hash_hmac('sha512',$uri,$apisecret);
        $ch = curl_init($uri);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'.$sign));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $execResult = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

}

for ($x = 0; $x < 4; $x++) {
        callapi($url, $flags, $apikey, $apisecret);
}
```

How would I switch/cycle interfaces (eth0, eth1, eth2) for my API call every 4th time?

Answer (score 0):

curl_setopt($curlh, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");